# Package does not exist when using Maven

Tags: mongodb, maven, netbeans

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>mavenproject1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>mavenproject1</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
       <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
      <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
      <version>2.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>
</project>
```

When I try to import com.mongodb, I get a package does not exist error. I had to manually add the .jar file to make it work. How do I get Maven dependency to work?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have the maven coordinate correct, and the artifact [does exist on maven central repository](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.mongodb%7Cmongo-java-driver%7C2.10.1%7Cjar). So I strongly believe your maven settings had configuration problem causing it unable to fetch from central repository.

This commonly occur when you're behind a company internal repository such as nexus and it has stale index, or you set your ~/.m2/settings.xml to NOT lookup from the central repo.

Comment: I'm not behind a company internal repository. How do I fix this error?

Comment: Run maven build and then check maven local repository - was requiqred artifact downloaded? If not, check settings.xml for proxy and repositories settings as suggested by @gerrytan.